# Getting hashes of Google Docs documents?

Tags: google-drive

Although Google Docs documents seem to have a unique ID in the URL, I'm wondering if there is a way to get a hash (MD5, SHA1) of a document without downloading it again. Has anyone attempted something similar? Is there some API call I can make?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [API call](https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/files), documented in at the link.

> md5Checksum:  string, An MD5 checksum for the content of this file. This
>   is populated only for files with content stored in Drive.

In java you can retrieve it by adding a line to [this java example](https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/files/get)

```
 System.out.println("MD5: " + file.getMd5Checksum());
```

Answer (score -1):

[Hashify.me](http://hashify.me/) stores the entire content of a webpage in its url.
Type your text in the editor box (supports Markdown) and watch the url self-updating instantly in your adress bar.

Comment: That's an interesting concept, but not really related to my question. I'm looking for one-way hashes (digital signatures) for my files already stored on Google Docs.